# getting different users logged in using different browsers

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
    <style type="text/css">
        .rTable {
            display: table;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = setupPage;
        function setupPage() {
            var state = { //state that you need when the callback is called
                output: document.getElementById("output"),
                startTime: new Date().getTime()
            };
            var callback = {
                onSuccess: layoutResults,
                onFailure: queryFailed,
                source: state
            };
            sforce.connection.query(
                "Select UsersId, UserType,IsCurrent,users.name From AuthSession where IsCurrent= true ",
                callback);
        }
        function queryFailed(error, source) {
            source.output.innerHTML = "An error has occurred: " + error;
        }
        function layoutResults(queryResult, source) {
            if (queryResult.size > 0) {
                var records = queryResult.getArray('records');
                for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                    var user = records[i];
                    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                    tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + user.UsersId + '</td>' + '<td>' + user.UserType + '</td>' + '<td>' + user.IsCurrent + '</td>' + '<td>' + user.Users.Name + '</td>';
                    document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(tr);
                }
                source.output.innerHTML = output;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <html>
    <table id="myTable">
        <!-- Header -->
        <tr>
            <td> Id </td>
            <td> Name </td>
            <td> iscurrent</td>
            <td> username</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

currently i had logged in 2 users, one is admin in chrome another is slead user in internet browser, But my code show only one user logged in, i want to get both the users,please ,,,,"i want a query that show shows all logged in users.(different browsers r different systems)need your help,thanks in advance

Comment: query returns 1 user both for admin and simple user?

Comment: my code returns 1 ..i.e..admin is only true ,,not showing the second user.

Comment: because of i logged in users,it has to show two users active means,isCurrent=true.

Answer (score 0):

Use query without `IsCurrent = true` to see all sessions

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm

> Description If true, the session is a member of the user’s current
>   session family. This field is available in API version 37.0 and later.